# Does Zig's fifo.pump support sendfile?

Tags: optimization, sendfile, zig

[Zig has `fifo.pump()`](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/master/lib/std/fifo.zig) which takes a reader and a writer? Does this support `sendfile` optimizations on Linux in any case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it should to be, but apparently it does not. From truemedian,

> Unfortunately not, `pump` would need to have a special case for handling the combination of `std.fs.File.Reader`/`std.net.Stream.Reader` and `std.fs.File.Writer`/`std.net.Stream.Writer` and it simply doesn't.

Source: https://github.com/orhun/zig-http-benchmarks/issues/16